# Do we know the age of Robb and Jon?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, adaptation-comparison, age

I would like to know whether Robb or Jon is older. I, for myself, haven't read the books. So do we know the (exact?) birth-dates of those "siblings" and can compare them?

As far as I know, we can't date Jon's birth exactly, as we don't know for sure who his mother is. But maybe we can assure a precise span of time? I think that Robb's birth, on the other hand, should be clear.

**So how old are Robb Stark and Jon Snow?**

Credits for the wise soul which can tell if there is a difference in the show and the books. I don't think there is one, but if I have to specify, I would like to know the ages in the books.

Please help me, as I know nothing.

Comment: Why the DVs on this question??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Robb and Jon are both 17 at the start of the show.  This is in contrast to the books where they are both 14 at the start.**

As to who is older, I don't think there is a Canon answer to this. The closest I'm aware of is this book quote implying that Robb is older.

> Many men fathered bastards. Catelyn had grown up with that knowledge. It came as no surprise to her, in the first year of her marriage, to learn that Ned had fathered a child on some girl chance met on campaign. He had a man’s needs, after all, and they had spent that year apart, Ned off at war in the south while she remained safe in her father’s castle at Riverrun. Her thoughts were more of Robb, the infant at her breast, than of the husband she scarcely knew. He was welcome to whatever solace he might find between battles.

I read this to say that Robb was conceived before Ned went off to war, while Jon was conceived during the war. (Obviously assuming that Catelyn's understanding of the situation is correct)

Adding detail related to the above quote to reflect Season 6.

> In season 6, we discover that Jon Snow is not Ned's son after all, but rather the son of his sister (Lyanna Stark) and Rhaegar Targaryen.  This is in contradiction to Catelyn's understanding of the situation and so invalidates the quote above as a legitimate source for this answer.

Due to this, the best that can be said at this point is that **Robb and Jon are very close in age.**

Comment: So answers in forums like "Robb's a few months older" is true? We can't be more certain than that? Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: @Trollwut Think the forum answers is the best we have right now. Don't know that the show ever addressed this either.

Comment: She was pregnant with Robb before Ned left for the campaign where he fathered Jon, so Robb has to be older.

Comment: @Kevin .. where *he* fathered Jon, yes..

Comment: @Kevin Ned brought back a baby. Whether that baby was due to Ned's infedelity on campaign is hotly debated. Best we can say is according to Catelyn's understanding of the situation, Robb is older

Answer (score 1):

In the show both boys appear to be 16/17 with the [wikia for Jon](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Jon_Snow#cite_note-0) stating the following of their ages:

> Jon is roughly the same age as Robb Stark, and they were both born near the end of Robert's Rebellion - which in the novels was 15 years before the beginning of the narrative, so they were both about 14. In the TV version, the rebellion was 17 years ago, **making Jon and Robb 16 in Season 1**. Six years pass in the TV series by Season 7.

As of the early seasons it appears that Jon must be slightly younger than Robb as he is Ned's bastard fathered during the rebellion. Whereas Robb is Ned's trueborn son to Catelyn fathered before he left for war.

However, as of Season 7 Episode 7, "The Dragon and the Wolf", it has been finally spelled out for us that:

> "Jon's real name is Aegon Targaryen. He's never been a bastard. He's the heir to the Iron Throne."
>
>
>  <sub>*Game of Thrones, Season 7 Episode 7, "The Dragon and the Wolf"*</sub>

As such it is unclear as to who was born first and so who is the older brother.

Answer (score 1):

Although they must be close in age as they are both born in 283 AC. Jon's age [is confirmed](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Years_after_Aegon%27s_Conquest/Calculations_Ages_(Continued)#Jon_Snow) through his turning of 14 to 15 while Robb's age [is confirmed](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Years_after_Aegon%27s_Conquest/Calculations_Ages_(Continued3)#Robb_Stark) through his turning of 15 to 16. This puts them both at 14 at the start of the books but....

## Jon is older!

Otherwise Catelyn would not have to worry about Jon's sons taking away from Robb's sons.

> If you make Jon legitimate, there is no way to turn him bastard again. Should he wed and breed, any sons you may have by Jeyne will never be safe.”
>
> *A Storm of Swords - Catelyn V*

In Westeros the [line of succession](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37862/comprehensive-rules-for-game-of-thrones-lines-of-succession) passes from father to first-born son and on down the line. This would mean if Jon were legitimate his son, then grandsons, and any other son in that line would have a greater claim than Robb and any of his sons or grandsons.

For Catelyn to worry about this issue Jon would would have to be older than Robb. If Robb were older the line of succession would always pass through him.

Answer (score -2):

With the unraveling of current events, it is undetermined who is older as

> Rhaegar Targaryen and Lyanna Stark

could have conceived Jon prior to Robb being conceived by Ned and Catelyn Stark.

Comment: Can you add anything that's not already said in the accepted answer?

Comment: @Mak.  In addition to not being very detailed (and repeating the updated part of my accepted answer), it's also a big spoiler for Season 6.  Major plot points (such as the parentage of a certain bastard), should be hidden behind spoiler tags.