# Who would be regent to new Lord of Bear Island if all adult Mormonts died?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

As we know according to the book, Maege is the Lady of Bear Island, with five daughters; Dacey, Alysane, Lyra, Jorelle, and Lyanna. Dacey dies at the Red Wedding, Alysane leaves with Ironborn, the whereabouts of Maege, Lyra, and Jorelle are unknown, even though they were together, while Lyanna was at home. Alysane is her mother's heir, and she has two children: a nine-year-old daughter and a two-year-old son.

So, the order of Bear Island heirs is:

- Maege
- Alysane
- her son
- her daughter
- Lyra
- Jorelle
- Lyanna

Lyanna and Alysanne's daughter are almost the same age, while Alysane's son is about seven years younger. The question is, what happens if Maege, Alysane, Lyra, and Jorelle all die in less than six years? Alysane's son would become Lord of Bear Island, and since he had not reached maturity (sixteen), he needed regent. However, in my case, the aunt (who would ideally be a regent) all that's left is Lyanna, who has also not reached maturity.

Who would be regent for him, considering all adult are dead? Or he just got advisors, like Bran when Robb went to war?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I'm not sure what you're asking.  You've pretty clearly laid out the line of succession here, so is your question really who would be regent assuming all the adults are killed?

Comment: Males always take priority in GoT rules of succession.  See here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/37862/57310

Comment: Is this a what-if scenario?

Answer (score 2):

## Heir

---

You are correct about the heir. The defacto law of inheritence for most nobles in ASOIAF is Agnatic-Cognatic Primogeniture. So if all Mormonts die except Alysanne's children and Lyanna, Alysanne's son will be the new Lord Mormont. If he dies, his sister will  inherit the title. Lyanna can inherit only if both of Alysanne's children die. However it must be kept in mind what GRRM has said about inheritence.

> The short answer is that the laws of inheritance in the Seven Kingdoms
> are modelled on those in real medieval history... which is to say,
> they were vague, uncodified, subject to varying interpretations, and
> often contradictory.
> <sub>[**So Spake
> Martin**](https://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Category/C91/P210/)</sub>

There are ample examples of Lords/Royals treating primogeniture as more of a custom than an actual binding law even though it is widely acknowledged to be the law everywhere north of Dorne.

Furthermore, Bran was not a Lord and hence got no regents. He was just the Stark in Winterfell, made part of the discussions by household Staff who ran the castle on behalf of its rightful owner, King Robb Stark.

## Regent

---

There is one tiny flawed premise in the question: Only family members (And that too from the same house) can become regents.

That is simply not true. Any adult noble can assume the charge of regent for a minor noble. It can be their kin, it can be a vassal, it can be someone appointed by the grand council of Lords of realm and it can be their household staff. Your kill-list seems to miss the father of Alysanne's children (assuming he is alive). He can very well assume the mantle of regency during minority of his children. If not him there are ample precedents for all the cases listed above.

#### Kins

1. Queen Mother Alyssa Velaryon served as regent for her son King Jaehaerys I.
2. [Garon](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Garon_Baratheon) Baratheon served as regent for Lord [Boremund](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Boremund_Baratheon) Baratheon.
3. Prince Aemond Targaryen served as regent for his brother King Aegon II, when the latter was incapacitated due to his wounds.
4. More recently, Lady Lysa Tully was regent for her son Lord Robert Arryn.

#### Vassals

1. Lord [Yorbert](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Yorbert_Royce) Royce served as regent for Lady [Jeyne](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jeyne_Arryn) Arryn.
2. Lord [Roland](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Roland_Westerling) Westerling was the regent for Lord [Loreon](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Loreon_Lannister) Lannister. The young lord was also Roland's grandson so he can also qualify for kins.
3. Most famously, King Aegon III had a council of seven regents during his minority which consisted of Lady Jeyne Arryn, Lord Royce Caron, Ser Torrhen Manderly, Lord Manfryd Mooton, Grandmaester Munkun, Lord Corlys Velaryon and Lord Roland Westerling. There were 6 subsequent replacements in this original council from time to time.
4. Lord Eddard Stark was named regent for King Joffrey. The role was later taken up by Queen Cersei.

#### Appointment by Grand Council

1. Lords William Stackspear, Lorent Grandison and Marq Merryweather were appointed by grand council of year 136 to the council of regents for King Aegon III.

#### Household

1. Septon [Robeson](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Robeson) served as regent for infant son of Lord [Damon Hightower](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Damon_Hightower).
2. An unnamed member of House Tyrell (Then serving as Household Staff to Kings of the Reach as Stewards) served as regent for [Garland](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Garland_VI_Gardener) VI Gardener.